# how to display table when the menu bar is is clicked?

Tags: java

may I know how to display out the table when the menu bar is clicked?

Below is my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Exercise03 extends JFrame {

    public Exercise03() {
        
        String[] columns = {
            "No", "DO NUMBERS", "INVOICE NUMBERS", "OUTLET", "SUBMITTED BY", "CHECKED BY"   
        };
        
        Object [][] input = new Object[][] {
            {"1", "NKK/DO200100001", "NKK/IV200100001", "K", "A", "B"}
        };
        
        JMenuBar menuBar;
        JMenu menu;
        JMenuItem menuItem1;
        
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        
        menu = new JMenu ("Menu");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        
        menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Invoice", KeyEvent.VK_I);
        menu.add(menuItem1);
        menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                JTable menuItem1 = new JTable(input, columns);
                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(menuItem1);
                pane.add(menuItem1);
                pane.setVisible(true);
                
            }
        });
        
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Documentation Checklist");
        setSize(300,100);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Exercise03();
                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Right now I am able to display out the "menu" bar and when I clicked it, it shows one submenus which is "Invoice" but when I clicked the submenu "Invoice", it does not shows out the table below the menu bar.

My expected output is when I click the submenu "Invoice", it will shows up a table below the menu bar.

So may I know how to code to display such result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to learn how to use a JScrollPane:

```
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(menuItem1);
//pane.add(menuItem1);
```

Only the first statement is needed. The scroll pane has a "viewport" to display the component. So the table needs to be added to the viewport, which is done automatically when you create the scroll pane with the table as the parameter in the constructor.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details on how the scroll pane works.

Then to dynamically add the scroll pane to the frame:

1. Don't change the layout to a FlowLayout. The default `BorderLayout` will be a better layout manager for the frame. It will allow components to resize dynamically as the frame is resized.
2. You create a JScrollPane, but you never add it to the frame. So you need to add the scroll pane to the frame. The setVisible() statement is not needed since all Swing components are visible by default
3. Once you add the scroll pane to the frame you need to invoke `revalidate()` on the panel you add the scroll pane to. In this case since you add it to the content pane you can just invoke `revalidate()` on the frame. The `revalidate()` will invoke the layout manager to give the scroll pane a size and location.

The other solution is to create the JScrollPane in the constructor of your class and add it to the frame. You would then need to save the scroll pane as an instance variable of your class. Then when you click on the menu item you can create the JTable and add the table to the scroll pane using:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( menuItem1 );
```

then you don't need to worry about the revalidate().